# How to assign dynamic text box values to corresponding models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular js application there are text boxes users can add dynamically and update the data. How to map those to the modals. Here is the simple problem that I derived from my current usecase.

```
    <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
        <td><input type="text" ng:model="personInfo.item.description"class="input-small"></td>           
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="personInfo.item.qty" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="personInfo.item.cost" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
        <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            [<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
        </td>
    </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranmca04/d81fzLzf/1/

I need to below json format when the user submit the page. Complete html file you can find in jsfiddle.

{info:[
       name: 'Albert',
       age: '33',
       items": [ { "desc": "test1", "qty": 1, "cost":33,},
                 { "desc": "test2", "qty": 2, "cost":4,},
                 { "desc": "test3", "qty": 1, "cost":1,}
               ]
       ]
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awakeningbyte/b25xo3Lw/1)

based on your code, personInfo should be a single object, not an array

```
var personInfo = {
    items: []
}

$scope.addItem = function() {
    personInfo.items.push({
        qty: 1,
        description: '',
        cost: 0
    });
},
$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    personInfo.items.splice(index, 1);
},

$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(personInfo.items, function(item) {
        total += item.qty * item.cost;
    })

    return total;
}
$scope.personInfo = personInfo

$scope.saveData = function (personInfo)
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(personInfo));
    console.log('info '+JSON.stringify(personInfo));
}

<tr ng:repeat="item in personalInfo.items">
    <td><input type="text" ng:model="item.description"class="input-small"></td>           
    <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.qty" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.cost" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
    <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
...
```

Comment: Hi.. as per your suggestion I have changed it, but i am getting undefined in the alert.  Here is the link  http://jsfiddle.net/ga8spqm5/3/    could you please take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awakeningbyte/b25xo3Lw/1/  you need to pass personalInfo to saveData function. ng-click="saveData(personInfo)" at line 36

Comment: It worked thank you. If you don't think it is silly question. I see every row in the request has another field  "$$hashKey":"008"  what is this?

Comment: it is added by angular.  I have updated the example code.  Change JSON.stringify to  angular.toJson() .